# How does Zend Server deal with database migrations during application deployment

Tags: php, migration, zend-studio, zend-server

So I've been playing around with Zend Server to deploy and manage my PHP Applications. The application deployment and roll back is kind of neat, but how does it deal with database migrations if there are any? Does anyone have any experience with it or know of a site that explains it? How about database rollbacks?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your own deploy and rollback scripts. Zend Server does not help you in any way with that; it only provides hook script entry points.

I've asked Eric Ritchie of Zend about this issue at the IPC in Frankfurt last week, and that's what he told me.

Comment: Yea that's what I figured. Thanks for asking it and clarifying =)